# Ruby AWS SNS Send SMS set Default Sender ID

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I am trying to set the DefaultSenderID for a SMS message in Ruby (Rails) with the AWS Ruby SDK (2).  I cannot seem to figure out exactly how I need to set the sms attributes hash.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This code works to send a simple message (I left out the secret keys, etc. of course)

```
require 'aws-sdk'

sns = Aws::SNS::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')
sns.publish(phone_number: 'MY_NUMBER', message: 'This is a test SMS message')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are close, but the message is not being passed in correctly. From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SNS/Client.html) you can find this example.

```
resp = client.publish({
  topic_arn: "topicARN",
  target_arn: "String",
  phone_number: "String",
  message: "message", # required
  subject: "subject",
  message_structure: "messageStructure",
  message_attributes: {
    "String" => {
      data_type: "String", # required
      string_value: "String",
      binary_value: "data",
    },
  },
})
```

I believe if you made a minor tweak it should work for you.

```
require 'aws-sdk'

sns = Aws::SNS::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')
sns.publish(phone_number: 'MY_NUMBER',
            message: 'This is a test SMS message',
            message_attributes: { data_type: "String" } )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am getting following error
    "exception": "#<Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError: unable to sign request without credentials set>",

Comment: @urjitonrails it sounds like the AWS credentials were not set on the project initialization. I would try checking that.

Comment: Actually I am getting this AWS response #<struct Aws::SNS::Types::PublishResponse message_id="00479629-bb20-5da2-96dd-cf2ae244142f", sequence_number=nil>

Comment: Actually  this is my question I ask on stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67301031/aws-sns-otp-sms-not-getting. If you can check and let me know the mistake will be grt help for me

Comment: do we required senderid to sent message?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with the exact same problem. Hope this code will help you:

```
sns = Aws::SNS::Client.new(region:  'eu-west-1')
sns.set_sms_attributes(attributes: { 'DefaultSenderID' => 'Custom' })
sns.publish( phone_number: phone_number, message: message)
```

Please note, that your country should be in [supported countries list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html). Also according to [naming rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html):

> For Sender ID, type a custom ID that contains up to 11 alphanumeric
>   characters, including at least one letter and no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

in my case

```
sns = Aws::SNS::Client.new(
      region: 'aws-region',
      access_key_id: 'aws-aid',
      secret_access_key: 'aws-sak'
    )

sns.publish({
    phone_number: 'phone_number',
    message: "msg",
    message_attributes: {
      "String": {
        data_type: "String",
        string_value: "String"
        }
      }
   })
```